# Show accordion content

Tags: html, css, accordion

Is it possible to remove accordion but still show content, at a certain breakpoint? In this example max-width 1000px.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}

/* BREAK POINT WHERE ACCORDION CONTENT SHOULD SHOW AND BUTTON DISSAPEAR */
@media (min-width: 1000px) { 
 button {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAPRC04352Z8

If i open the buttons, and expand the window it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Just override all properties that potentially hide your panel content ([modified code on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAPRUURICDA3)):

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) { 
    button {display: none;}
    div.panel { opacity: 1; max-height: none}
}
```

By using this solution (with CSS only) you also keep the `.show` class on the panels. Thus when resizing the window again, your previously shown panels are shown and hidden panels are hidden again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thanks for the answer - it worked!